# Amcharts Stacked Column Chart with Line Chart put valueaxis below line chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, line, amcharts, stacked

I've prepared a chart where stacked column chart combined with line chart. Now the total value of stacked chart i.e the valueaxis should be on stacked column. But the total value showing over line chart. 
Without line chart it is perfect.
[image]
But with line chart the total value goes up.
[image]
Here is my code

```
$scope.chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        "type": "serial",
        "theme": "none",
        "legend": {
            "position": "top",
            "useGraphSettings": true,
            "align": "center"
        },
        "dataProvider": $scope.monthly_chart_data,
        "valueAxes": [{
            "stackType": "regular",
            "axisAlpha": 0.3,
            "gridAlpha": 0,
            "totalText": "[[total]]"
        }],
        "graphs": [{
            "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "lineAlpha": 0.0,
            "title": "Betrag",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#000000",
            "valueField": "Rechnung",
            "fillColors": "#003d6a"
        }, {
            "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "lineAlpha": 0.0,
            "title": "Bestellung",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#000000",
            "valueField": "Bestellung",
            "fillColors": "#8673a4"
        }, {
            "id": "graph2",
            "lineThickness": 1.5,
            "fillAlphas": 0,
            "lineAlpha": 1,
            "lineColor": "#e95f30",
            "title": "Budget",
            "valueField": "Budget",
            "dashLengthField": "dashLengthLine",
            "stackable": false
        }],
        "categoryField": "month",
        "categoryAxis": {
            "gridPosition": "start",
            "axisAlpha": 0,
            "gridAlpha": 0,
            "position": "left"
        },
        "numberFormatter" : {
            "precision": -1,
            "decimalSeparator": ",",
            "thousandsSeparator": "."
        }
    });
```

How do I put total value i.e valueaxis over stacked column but below line chart? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line axis is being added to the same stack; `stacked` applies to the entire value axis and all graphs associated it, not just specific graphs or types, so the line is also included in the stack and totals. If you don't want the line to be included in the stack and its totals, simply assign it to a different value axis.

```
    "synchronizeGrid": true, //optional if you want both axes to have the same scale. Doesn't always work, though.
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "regular",
        "axisAlpha": 0.3,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "totalText": "[[total]]"
    },{
        "id": "valueAxis2",  //create second axis for the line graph
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "right",
        "gridAlpha": 0
    }],
    "graphs": [
     // ...
     {
        "id": "graph2",
        "valueAxis": "valueAxis2", //assign line graph to valueAxis2
        "lineThickness": 1.5,
        "fillAlphas": 0,
        "lineAlpha": 1,
        "lineColor": "#e95f30",
        "title": "Budget",
        "valueField": "Budget",
        "dashLengthField": "dashLengthLine",
        "stackable": false
    }]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes it partially works but without proper indicator/valuaxis how do i know what my line chart indicate?

Comment: Re-enable the axis labels and position it on the right then. I updated my snippet. Note that it will have its own scale, so you might want to synchronize the axes somehow by setting the same min/max. A quick way to do that is to set `synchronizeGrid` on the top level of your config object.

Comment: It works for me. Post a working fiddle with your chart code and randomized/sample data so I can take a look.

Comment: What part of this doesn't work? The totals are only including the stacked bars like you wanted. If you want the second value axis to indicate what the line is pointing to, replace the value axis definition with what I provided in my updated answer as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a2q9jzme/).